# How to format DateTime using model binding

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, datetime, webforms, string-formatting

I am using entity framework in an asp.net web forms application, and binding my model using code nuggets / directives. I have a DateTime field -*ClosedDate*- and I am trying to display the hours between that and the current date and time, which represents the remaining hours. The value it produces without formatting it is correct, I just want to change the format.

For 2 hours and 30 minutes remaining, it is displayed as 2.50000000000000, and I would like it displayed as either 2 or 2.5. I tried toString() with custom format strings, but could not get the correct value

**The Code**

```
<%# Item.ClosedDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalHours%>
```

This produces 2.50000000000000

```
<%# Item.ClosedDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalHours.ToString("hh")%>
```

This produces hh

```
<%# Item.ClosedDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now).ToString("hh")%>
```

This produces 02, which is fine, but when ClosedDate is greater than 24 hours, the value is not correct.

When ClosedDate = *2013-12-10 01:10:25.000* and DateTime.Now = *2013-12-07 20:20:00.000*, the value produced was 04.

When ClosedDate = *2013-12-10 19:54:11.000* and DateTime.Now = *2013-12-07 20:20:00.000*, the value produced was 23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things here. This:

```
Item.ClosedDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalHours
```

returns a `double`, and this:

```
Item.ClosedDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now)
```

returns a `TimeSpan`, not a `DateTime`.

So, you've been trying to format a `double` or a `TimeSpan` as an hour `"hh"`, but the time and date format specifiers should only be used with `DateTime` structs. If you just want the difference in hours with a specific number of decimal places, use a built-in or custom number format that will pad your result, such as:

```
Item.ClosedDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalHours.ToString("#0.##");
```

The above should display 2.5 as `2.5`, and 2.0 as `2`.

See the [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation on MSDN for more examples.